# Laravel 5.3 Mailable.php not found

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.3

I want to make send mail with Laravel 5.3 and it gives me this error when I try to: `vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`. I checked te directory and saw that this file really does not exist.
In the controller where I want to send the mail I use

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

use App\Mail\OrderMail;
```

So how can I generate this file to send the mail ?

Answer (score 1):

For generating Mailables laravel has a nice command `php artisan make:mail OrderMail`

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to create a new Laravel app with 5.3 and this file is there.

Make sure you have the correct version of the framework in `composer.json`:

```
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.*"
```

And then try to run `composer install`.

If you have a `composer.lock` check the version there too.